# @Query not working as expected : No property findAllServices found for type 'Param'

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa

I'm new to java. I would like to create a get api, that returns this

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.* FROM param p INNER JOIN student_service pa ON p.name = pa.service
```

but I got this error

> Failed to create query for method public abstract java.util.List
> com.myapp.repository.ParamRepository.findAllServices()! No property
> findAllServices found for type 'Param'

Repository

```
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;


import java.util.List;

@Repository
public interface ParamRepository extends JpaRepository<Param, Long> {

    @Query(name = "SELECT DISTINCT p.* FROM param p INNER JOIN student_service pa ON p.name = pa.service", nativeQuery = true)
    List<Param> findAllServices();
}
```

Service

```
public interface ParamService {
    public List<ParamDto> getAllServices();
}
```

ServiceImp

```
@Service
    public class ParamServiceImpl implements ParamService {
    
        private final ParamRepository paramRepository;
        private final ParamMapper paramMapper;
    
        public ParamServiceImpl(ParamRepository paramRepository, ParamMapper paramMapper) {
            this.paramRepository = paramRepository;
            this.paramMapper = paramMapper;
        }
         @Override
            public List<ParamDto> getAllServices() {
               return paramMapper.toParamDtos(paramRepository.findAllServices());
            }
    }
```

Controller

```
@GetMapping(path = "/services")
public List<ParamDto> getAllServices() {
  return paramService.getAllServices();
}
```

The two entities

Param

```
Table(name = "param")
public class Param implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "PARAM_PK_SEQ")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "PARAM_PK_SEQ", sequenceName = "PARAM_PK_SEQ", allocationSize = 1)
    private Long id;

    public String name;
    private String description;
}
```

Student

```
Table(name = "student")
public class Student implements Serializable {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "STUDENT_PK_SEQ")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "STUDENT_PK_SEQ", sequenceName = "STUDENT_PK_SEQ", allocationSize = 1)
        private Long id;
    
        private String name;
        private String age;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(
            name = "student_service",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "student"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "service", referencedColumnName = "name"))
    private List<Param> services;
    }
```

Thank you in advance for your time and help!

Comment: Can you paste the Repository interface definition?

Comment: @pholak I updated my code above

Comment: You updated the service but I asked about `interface ParamRepository`

Comment: Sorry, I updated it now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should change `name` to `value` in `@Query` annotation

From:

```
@Query(name = "SELECT DISTINCT p.* FROM param p INNER JOIN student_service pa ON p.name = pa.service", nativeQuery = true)
List<Param> findAllServices();
```

to:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT DISTINCT p.* FROM param p INNER JOIN student_service pa ON p.name = pa.service", nativeQuery = true)
List<Param> findAllServices();
```